# Связать выпадающие списки rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

Как исключить из второго списка выбранный в первом списке пункт ?

```
<%= f.select(:city_2, @city_select)  %>

<%= f.select(:city_1, @city_select)   %>
```

Comment: Только Javascript'ом. Рекомендую добавить соответствующие теги и привести получающуюся из этих двух строк разметку, чтобы JS'ерам было что сказать на это.

Answer (score 1):

`RoR` это бекенд, он ничего не знает о том, что происходит у вас во фронт-енде до тех пор, пока вы не отправите в него эти данные.
`Ajax` тут и не нужен, тут нужен `Javascript`.

Comment: Минус не мой, но я могу объяснить, за что он: он ни на шаг не приближает автора к решению. Здесь куда продуктивнее добиться правки вопроса автором, чтобы адепты JavaScript могли рассказать, как это делается. Не спешите отвечать на вопросы, которые ещё толком не оформились.