# Выпадающий список RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как получить данные из таблицы в первом списке, а в следующем списке без выбранных данных из первого списка. не используя Ajax или без него нельзя?

```
<%= f.select(:room_2, @room_select) %>
<%= f.select(:room_1, @room_select) %>
```

Comment: Недавно было задано примерно то же самое: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515103/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-rails#comment628948_515103